# Regarding Oracle Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am getting the below oracle error.  I checked  the test scheme for any constraint name CMF_CMP using toad. But i am unable to find it. 
How do i detect the reason for failure and how to resolve it.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: -2298: ORA-02298: cannot validate (TEST.FMF_CMP) - parent keys not found
ORA-06512: at test.test_SYN", line 46
```

Comment: And what is content of test.test_SYN?

Comment: Can you run this on top of your TOAD check: "SELECT * FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_name = 'FMF_CMP'". Also - is the "CMF_CMP" you mentioned only a typo at SO or did you make it in your check too?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Problem there were orphaned child record and when the constraints are enabled i got this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have an orphan!
You'll need to track it down and give it a parent or drop the orphan

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora02298.php

```
select * 
  from test_SYN ts
 where PARENTID not EXISTS(
                           select NULL 
                             from test_PARENT tp
                            where tp.ID = ts.ParentID)
```

Are you trying to enable the constraint or am I just missing the mark?